# Why are the properties of my instance undefined?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a script for rendering an animation on a page, I'm part way through [this tutorial](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-sprite-animation/).  I define a sprite class and then create an instance called coin, but coin's properties don't seem to be defined.  The debugger says my context is undefined when it tries to run coin.render(), but I don't see what's wrong with my instantiation.

I can supply the html or image if needed.

```
window.onload = function () {

var spriteSheet = new Image();
spriteSheet.src = "spriteSheet.jpg";

//define sprite class

function sprite(options) {

    var that = {};

    this.context = options.context;
    this.width = options.width;
    this.height = options.height;
    this.image = options.image;

    that.render = function() {

        that.context.drawImage(
            that.image,
            0,
            0,
            that.width,
            that.height,
            0,
            0,
            that.width,
            that.height
        );

    }

    return that;

}

var canvas = document.getElementById("coinAnimation");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;

var coin = sprite({
        context: canvas.getContext("2d"),
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        image: spriteSheet
});

//alert(coin.width);

coin.render();

}
```

Comment: This line: `var coin = sprite({` should be `var coin = new sprite({`

Comment: `that.context` is not defined? Did you mean `var that = this` instead of `var that = {}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only thing wrong with it is the line:

```
var coin = sprite({
```

should be

```
var coin = new sprite({
```

The first one tells JavaScript to execute the constructor as a function. The second one tells JS to create a new instance.

Also, the variable `that` is an empty object. You need to assign it `this` not `{}`

Comment: I tried that and I still get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'drawImage' of undefined.

Comment: @zbnrg The variable `that` is an empty object: `var that = {};`

Comment: ah, this and that, I kept seeing the word that and automatically switching it to this in my head.  Thank you all.

Comment: @jakekimds go ahead...I did have a nice answer written out and right as I go to post, someone marked it as a duplicate lol